# why does .prepend() work only once?

Tags: jquery, events, dom, prepend

I'm making a todo-list application, i use jQuery in it and when the user hit the `Add` button a new task get appended to the `tasksWrapper` div, but the problem is, it only happen once. When i press the  `Add` button again, nothing happen. I've checked the DOM tree, still the same with only one `mainTaskFrag` prepended . Here's my code :

```
$(function(){
    var mainTaskFrag = $("<div class='wholeTask'>"),
    mainTaskContents = $('<div class="mainTaskWrapper clearfix">\
                            <div class="mainMarker"></div>\
                            <label for="task1">This is task1</label>\
                            <div class="holder"></div>\
                            <div class="subTrigger"></div>\
                            <div class="checkButton"></div>\
                            <div class="optTrigger"></div>\
                            <div class="mainOptions">\
                                <ul>\
                                    <li id="mainInfo">Details</li>\
                                    <li id="mainDivide">Divide</li>\
                                    <li id="mainEdit">Edit</li>\
                                    <li id="mainDelete">Delete</li>\
                                </ul>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>');    

  mainTaskFrag.prepend(mainTaskContents);

  $("#addMain").on("click", function(){                
      $("#tasksWrapper").prepend(mainTaskFrag);
  });    
});
```

​

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem with a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clone` method:

```
$("#addMain").on("click", function(){             
      $("#tasksWrapper").prepend(mainTaskFrag.clone());
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, i never thought of that, i actually thought that `.prepend()` just takes a copy of `mainTaskFrag` and prepend it.

Comment: @Rafael Yes, `prepend` doesn't `clone` the object.

Answer (score 0):

Because the bind to `$("#addMain")` is no longer there. If you do the bind again, it should work, although I'm sure someone will come up with a better way to do it that doesn't involve binding again.

Answer (score 0):

The `.prepend()` method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery's collection object(To insert it as the last child, use `.append()`).